# MATCHing AGAINST the word "Different" in MySQL (IN BOOLEAN MODE)

Tags: mysql, sql

This seems strange to me, but when using MATCH AGAINST in a query, I'm getting empty result sets when I try to match against the word "Different" which, in this database, happens to be a company name. When I query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE MATCH (company) AGAINST ('Different' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`
```

I get no results.

When I change the company name in the database to "Diffrnt" and query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE MATCH (company) AGAINST ('Diffrnt' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

it returns the information for that company as expected. In fact, in all other cases I've tried, it behaves normally.

Any ideas? I'm using MyWebSQL 3.3. I haven't been working in SQL for very long, so I hope I'm not missing anything, but I couldn't find anything in the MySQL MATCH AGAINST docs.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word **`"different"`** is on the [default] Full-Text Stopword list.

Reference here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-stopwords.html

Comment: +1, there's another part in the documentation as how to disable stopwords. Please do so selectively (by taking the original stopword file and removing those you don't want to be omitted) or your full text index may become (very) bloated: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html